# How to loop itertools through a list of files?

Tags: python, loops, python-itertools

I manage to create this for single file to slice down the line in a file. I would like to take odd number only.

```
filename = sys.argv[1]
filename2 = sys.argv[2]

with open(filename) as f:
    items = itertools.islice(f, 0, None, 2)

    x = (list(items))
    final = "".join(x)

with open(filename2, 'a+') as bb:
    bb.write(final)
```

Above code is working fine. But I need to specify the file name manually. What if I had 100 files that I need to slice?

Example what above code output. It will slice/remove the line on even number.

```
Input file
a
b
c
d
e

Output file
a
c
e
```

I'm thinking of loop. So far here's my solution.

```
# Directory where it contains my pat files.
mydir = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Scripts\\"
files = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.pat'), os.listdir(mydir))

# print(list(files))
# ['filepat1.pat', 'filepat2.pat', 'filepat3.pat'.......]

i = 0
new_file = 'file{}.pat'.format(i)

for file in files:
    with open(file) as f:
       items = itertools.islice(f, 0, None, 2)
       x = (list(items))
       final = "".join(x)
       #print(final)
       for item in items:
           i +=1
           new_file = 'file{}.pat'.format(i)
           with open(new_file, 'a+') as ww:
               ww.write(final)
```

What is my mistake? Seems like it missing the loop.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Why are you opening the file in `a+` mode just to read from it? That'll mean you always read nothing. And you weren't doing it in your original code, before adding the loop.

Comment: No error. But the files is not slice down. So I'm thinking it maybe something wrong with the loop. Because when debug print "file" the list is empty.

Comment: @abarnert oh my mistake. it got mess up with the copy and paste. I'll edit it now. But the result is still same.

Comment: What do you mean "the files is not slice down"? Can you reduce this to a [mcve]—maybe two 5-line input files, and the expected and actual output? There's really no way to debug a problem when we don't even know what the problem is.

Comment: @abarnert I've updated the input and output files :)

Comment: You still haven't shown us the incorrect output you're getting from the loop version. I assume it's different in some way from what you get in the original code, or you wouldn't be asking a question here, but "Seems like it missing the loop" doesn't tell me how it's different.

Comment: Anyway, another difference between your two versions: in the first version, after `x = list(items)`, you use `x`. In the second version, after `x = list(items)`, you ignore `x` and try to reuse `items`. Is that another copy-and-paste mess-up, or is that maybe your actual problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the code from `for item in items:` looks strange. From what I understand, you are trying to pull odd lines from one file and store them in a new file, right?

You can rewrite like this:

```
mydir = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Scripts\\"
files = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.pat'), os.listdir(mydir))

#print(list(files))

for i, file in enumerate(files):
    with open(file) as f:
       items = itertools.islice(f, 0, None, 2)
       x = (list(items))
       final = "".join(x)
       #print(final)

       new_file = 'file{}.pat'.format(i)
       with open(new_file, 'a+') as ww:
           ww.write(final)
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thanks for helping friend :)

And I've fixed minor issue on code above.